# How to get data behind shadow-root (open) in selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom

I want to get the data in the redbox which comes after shadow-root, how do I got about doing this.
I have tried using xpaths and css_selectors without any luck.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= "C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://betfury.io/sport-betting')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="popup-btn-close"]').click() #close pop_up
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="bettech"]') # this works
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="bt3306"]') # this does not work
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of that like below :

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root


outer = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.bt-inner-page"))
inner = outer.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="bt3306"]')
inner.click()
```

additionally,  this `bt3306` looks bit dynamic. so try with reliable class or any other locater. but as far as Shadow-root is concerned you can get rid off that by using the above code

**Update 1 :**

We were doing it wrong since `bt-inner-page` is an id, we have to use `#` not `.`

```
 def expand_shadow_element(element):
      shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
      return shadow_root

outer = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#bt-inner-page"))
    inner = outer.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-editor-id='navbarIcon']//*[name()='svg']")
    inner.click()
```

Comment: I am still getting this error message - 

```NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.bt-inner-page"}```

Comment: okay, updated the code above @Joe, try it out and let us know if you face any issue

Comment: ```Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='bt3306'] because of the following error:
NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The node provided is '#document-fragment', which is not a valid context node type.```


Now getting the following issue...

Comment: okay as I mentioned in my answer, bt3306 looks bit dynamic, which element you are looking in UI ?

Comment: So I used the xpath above it to make sure this wasn't the problem, and got the same error message - ```Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@dir='ltr'] because of the following error:
NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The node provided is '#document-fragment', which is not a valid context node type.
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)```

Comment: You need to tell me which element is that in UI  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235624/discussion-between-joe-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @Joe : Can you try with the updated answer above  ?